# FFMPEG or other tool to read .SDP file and save to file

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-streaming

I have a .sdp file describing an incoming multicast stream.

Can FFMPEG be used to read this .sdp file and save the incoming stream to disk, in a format such as .mp4?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, see the sdp demuxer; run `ffmpeg -h demuxer=sdp` for options.

Comment: Have you tried it? Which problems did you run into?